# What is the oldest still running music festival?

Tags: festival

What is the oldest still running music festival? 1970 - Pinkpop festival is at least a start, but I'm sure there are older ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, it's the Three Choirs Festival - running in the UK every year since 1719. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Choirs_Festival

Comment: That takes place about 10 miles from where I live - never been ! What a waste !